# How I can know when it's the first I'm a user sign in?

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

## My problem

I want to know when a user connect for the first time with Google on my app (firebase). I use `auth.signInWithPopup(googleProvider);`.

I searched in the docs and I found this : [AdditionalUserInfo - Type aliases](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth#additionaluserinfo). In it there's this :

```
AdditionalUserInfo: { isNewUser: boolean; profile: Object | null; providerId: string; username?: string | null }
```

The `isNewUser` is what I search for but I don't know how to use this "type aliases". When I do :

```
import { auth } from './firebase'

console.log(auth.AdditionalUserInfo);
```

Typescript and my IDE tell me that there's no `AdditionalUserInfo` !

My 'firebase.ts' file :

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/firestore';
var firebaseConfig = {some secret stuff...};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const auth = firebase.auth();
export const googleProvider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

export const db = firebase.firestore();
```

My App.svelte :

```
<script lang="ts">
    import { auth, googleProvider, db } from './firebase';
    import { authState } from 'rxfire/auth';
import { ArgumentOutOfRangeError } from 'rxjs';

    let user;
    let list;
    let signedin:boolean = false;

    function getTodos() {
        
        const todos = db.collection('todos-list').doc(auth.currentUser.displayName+"'s List")
        todos.onSnapshot(doc => {
            list = doc.data();
            console.log(list)
        }); 

    }

    const unsubscribe = authState(auth).subscribe(u => user = u);

    function login() {
        auth.signInWithPopup(googleProvider);
        signedin = true;

        console.log()

        getTodos()
    }

    function signout() {
        auth.signOut()
        signedin = false;
    }

</script>

<main>
    {#if signedin}
        <button on:click={ signout }>Sign Out</button>
        <h1>{ user.displayName }</h1>
        <img src="{ user.photoURL }" alt="">
    {/if}

    {#if !signedin}
        <button on:click="{ login }">Sign in With Google</button>
    {/if}
</main>
```

Here's my package.json :

```
{
  "name": "svelte-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rollup -c",
    "dev": "rollup -c -w",
    "start": "sirv public --no-clear",
    "validate": "svelte-check"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^17.0.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^11.0.0",
    "rollup": "^2.3.4",
    "rollup-plugin-css-only": "^3.1.0",
    "rollup-plugin-livereload": "^2.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-svelte": "^7.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-terser": "^7.0.0",
    "svelte": "^3.0.0",
    "svelte-check": "^1.0.0",
    "svelte-preprocess": "^4.0.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^8.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.0.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "@tsconfig/svelte": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^8.4.1",
    "rxfire": "^4.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.7",
    "sirv-cli": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

### Please help me !

Comment: share more info. your package.json.

Comment: I just added it, sorry !

Comment: The `AdditionalUserInfo` is only available from the `AuthCredential` object, which is right after the user signs in.

Also see: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67167954/how-i-can-know-when-its-the-first-im-a-user-sign-in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in nodejs/js client there is no `AdditionalUserInfo`. you can:

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.metadata.creationTime === firebase.auth().currentUser.metadata.lastSignInTime
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful, I’ve been searching for this for 3h...

Comment: i am glad it helped. feel free to upvote this answer and mark is as "accepted"...